# creating (adding) unique variables in a dataset between 2 dates

Tags: r

I have a dataset with unique station locations for acoustic receivers and both deployment and recovery dates for those stations. I am trying to plot the deployments by months but some of the receivers have been deployed for several years and the dataset does not currently capture each month the receiver was in the water.

I would like to calculate the difference between the recovery and deployment dates and then fill in (add) new unique entries by month to the data set for the time each receiver was deployed (eg. 2013, Jan-Dec, 2014, Jan-Jun).

This was my code I was working with but of course, it is just plotting the month of the deployment

```
deploy<-read.csv("Deployment_Database_CLEAN_MONTH2.csv",header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors = F)
deploy <- st_as_sf(deploy,coords = c("stn_long","stn_lat"), crs = 4326) ###

detect_can<-detect[detect$EEZ=='Canada',]

p <-  ggplot(land.all) + 
  geom_sf() +
  geom_sf(data=deploy,col='blue', alpha = 0.5)+ 
  geom_sf(data=detect_can,col='red')+ 
  xlab('Longitude')+ylab('Latitude')+
  coord_sf(xlim = c(-75, -45), ylim = c(40, 55), expand = FALSE) +
  facet_wrap(~Month) +
  #facet_wrap(format(deploy$Month[seq(1, length(deploy$Month), 12)],))+
  theme_bw()

ggsave(plot = p, filename = "figure MONTH4.jpg", width = 16, height = 12)
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!